# Como empezar a escribir luego de 3 caracteres

Tags: c#

Tengo un formulario de consulta que cada producto que consulta tiene una identificacion constante mas un numero que se genera automatico. me explico:

la constante es: INM y luego de eso viene un numero, ejemplo INM01 eso es un registro en la tabla, hay alguna forma por la cual cuando el usuario haga click en el textbox se ubique el cursor luego del INM (INM esta declarado en la propiedad text del textbox) para que el usuario solo tenga que escribir el numero?

Comment: Hola Samuel, puedes publicar el código para poder asistirte mejor.

Comment: La forma que planteas tiene el problema de que tienes que controlar muchas cosas en el validador del campo para que el usuario siempre introduzca un valor correcto, puesto que si modifica el prefijo tendrás que volver a añadirlo, comprobar que el resultado es válido, etc... ¿No te conviene más añadirlo antes de insertarlo en la BD de forma interna? Si quieres que el usuario sepa que no tiene que meterlo, podrías indicarlo añadiendo un campo "Disabled" delante del textbox con el prefijo, así el usuario ya sabe que no tiene que ponerlo. **EDIT** Algo así: https://jsfiddle.net/pth0osxv/

Comment: Porfavor, modifica la pregunta y agrega la tecnología que usas, no es lo mismo usar Asp.net, que WinForms o Wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independientemente de lo que estes utilizando, puedes decirle al usuario que escriba unicamente el numero en el cuadro de texto, por ejemplo 01 y mediante codigo le concatenas el INM a lo que el usuario escribio.

```
public void EventoConsulta(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string textoBuscar = "INM" + textbox1.Text;
    // Flujo normal para realizar la consulta
}
```

Algo asi podria ser.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es cada vez que se modifique el TextBox se compruebe que contiene el prefijo, si no lo contiene, añadirlo. Puedes usar como ejemplo:

```
public void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string prefix = "INM"

    if(this.value.indexOf(prefix) != 0 ){
        this.value = prefix + this.value;
    }
}
```